# ZeroRPC auto-assign free port number

Tags: python, sockets, port, zeromq

I am using ZeroRPC for a project, where there may be multiple instances running on the same machine. For this reason, I need to abe able to auto-assign unused port numbers. I know how to accomplish this with regular sockets using `socket.bind(('', 0))` or with ZeroMQ using the `bind_to_random_port` method, but I cannot figure out how to do this with ZeroRPC.

Since ZeroRPC is based on ZeroMQ, it must be possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there indeed a need to have the port-numbers **random**, or does having the port-numbers guaranteed to be **disjunct** from those already assigned port-numbers fit your design-needs?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct. What I want is to auto-assign free port numbers. I've reformulated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Having read details about ZeroRPC-python current state, the safest option to solve the task would be to create a central **`LotterySINGLETON`**, that would receive <-**`REQ`**/**`REP`**-> send a next free `port#` upon an instance's request.

This approach is isolated from ZeroRPC-dev/mod(s) modifications of use of the otherwise stable ZeroMQ API and gives you the full control over the port#-s pre-configured/included-in/excluded-from `LotterySINGLETON`'s draws.

The other way aroung would be to try to by-pass the ZeroRPC layer and ask ZeroMQ directly about the next random port, but the ZeroRPC documentation discourages from bypassing their own controls imposed on (otherwise pure) ZeroMQ framework elements ( which is quite a reasonable to be emphasised, as it erodes the ZeroRPC-layer consistency of it's add-on operations & services, so it shall rather be "obeyed" than "challenged" in trial/error ... )

Answer (score 0):

The following will let ZMQ choose a free port:

```
s = zerorpc.Server(SomeClass())
s.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:0')
```

The problem with this is that now you don't know which port it bound to. I managed to find the port with netstat and successfully connected to it, but that's probably not what you want to do. I made a seperate question out of this: [Find out bound ports of zerorpc server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186797/find-out-bound-ports-of-zerorpc-server)