# Find out bound ports of zerorpc server

Tags: port, rpc, zeromq

When I bind a zerorpc server instance to a random port as follows:

```
s = zerorpc.Server(SomeClass())
s.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:0')
```

How can I find out which port the server actually bound to? Another question leading to the same goal: How can I access zerorpc-server's underlying ZMQ socket?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the socket objects, I wrote a function that recursively searches for any ZMQ objects inside the vars(server_object):

```
def find_sockets(obj, thiskey, keys_before, results):
    if 'zmq.' in str(type(obj)):
        results.append(keys_before + [thiskey])
    try:
        vars(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return
    for key in vars(obj):
        find_sockets(vars(obj)[key], key, keys_before + [thiskey], results)

s = zerorpc.Server(Dummy())
s.bind('tcp://*:0')
results = []
find_sockets(s, '', [], results)
```

I find the following socket objects:

```
server_object
├─ _multiplexer
│  ├─ _events
│  │  ├ _send
│  │  │ └─ _socket
│  │  ├─ _recv
│  │  │  └─ _socket
│  │  └─ _socket
├─ _events
│  ├ _send
│  │ └─ _socket
│  ├─ _recv
│  │  └─ _socket
│  └─ _socket
```

After binding, calling getsockopt(zmq.LAST_ENDPOINT) on any of these socket objects gives me the connected endpoint and thus the port.

However this is probably not intended by the zeroRPC developers and not guaranteed to work in the future. Thus, what I do now in order to connect to a random free port, is to get a random port, try to bind to it, and repeat that until no zmq.ZMQError is thrown.